# Fundamental group of extended complex plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, fundamental-groups

I am reading [lecture notes of Riemann surfaces](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Earmin/lect/Riemann_surfaces.pdf) and encountering something I cannot understand.

[image]

[image]

As is shown in **Example 4.5**, the fundamental group of $\mathbb C^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. However, it implies that $\mathbb C^*$ is not simply connected, which contradicts

$$\pi_1(S^2)=\{0\}.$$

But I can't see where I go wrong. Any comments is appreciated:)

Comment: The star means invertible complex numbers, i.e. nonzero complex numbers, not the compactification. So you’re topologically looking at the punctured plane.

Comment: Thank you. I've figured it out!

Comment: It might help, that $\mathbb{C}^*=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent (which preserves homotopy groups) to $S^1$ and $\pi_1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ (which is generated by the identity $\operatorname{id}\colon S^1\rightarrow S^1$). Showing this with deck transformations is exactly the same: The universal covering is $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1,t\mapsto e^{it}$ and the deck transformations are again the translations $\{\tau_n|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question was answered in the comments, but let me give an offcial answer to clear it from the "unanswered" queue.

The space $\mathbb C^*$ does not denote the Riemann sphere (which is homeomorphic to $S^2$), but the punctured complex plane $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. This is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, hence $\pi_1(\mathbb C^*) \cong \mathbb Z$.

Notation is explained in the linked paper:

Section **Notation** on page ii :

- We use $\mathbb C^* = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$

Page 1 :

- Example 1.3 (Riemann sphere). Let $\hat{\mathbb C} := \mathbb C ∪ \{∞\}$

But even without these explicit definitions it is clear from the context that  $\mathbb C^*$ must denote the punctured complex plane. The author considers the universal covering $\exp : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^*$. Coverings are surjective by definiton, and the image $\exp(\mathbb C)$ is precisely the punctured complex plane.

Comment: As a side remark: Some authors require covering maps to be surjective, some don’t. For instance, Hatcher in his *Algebraic Topology* doesn't (in case that the base space is connected, his covering maps are surjective, though). In the lecture notes quoted by the OP, covering maps are necessarily surjective — so all is fine here.